# Python/Open3D: How to set axis labels, ticks, and control the window size etc

Tags: python, plot, 3d, open3d

I am trying to use Open3D to plot a large .laz file. I am looking to do the following:

a) ways to set the labels for X,Y,Z axes

b) See the dimensions of the X/Y/Z axes (the "ticks")

c) Get back the control to the python/spyder (without waiting for the window to be closed)

Below is the sample code.

```
import open3d as o3d 
import numpy as np

points = np.random.randn(1000,3)
colors  = np.ones((1000,3))*0.7
pc = o3d.geometry.PointCloud()
pc.points = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(points)
pc.colors = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(colors)
o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([pc])
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77180556/1874627 see this answer on how to have non-blocking visualization. There is no need to create separate thread

Answer (score 0):

For set axis you need to do like this:

```
points = np.random.randn(1000,3)
colors  = np.ones((1000,3))*0.7
pcd = o3d.geometry.PointCloud()
pcd.points = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(points)
pcd.colors = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(colors)
axis = o3d.geometry.TriangleMesh.create_coordinate_frame(size=3, 
origin=pcd.get_center())
o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([pcd, axis])
```

if you want to change window size, just to add this:

```
o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([pcd, axis], window_name='myCloud', 
                                  left=100,  #  This is offset
                                  top=100,   #  This is offset
                                  width=400, #  This is win size
                                  height=400 
                                  )
```

And if you want Get back the control to the python/spyder (without waiting for the window to be closed). You need to wrap all off your code to function and run it to another thread