# open3d dynamic point clouds rendering issue

Tags: rendering, point-clouds, open3d

I have to render a dynamically acquired point cloud. The pointcloud is segmented into objects that are rendered individually as geometries. Whenever an existing object moves, its geometry is updated. Whenever a new object enters the scene, a new geometry is added. Here comes the issue,  each time a new geometry is added, the renderer's viewpoint changes. I have not found the correct way how to stabilize the viewpoint to a fixed extrinsics. Any help is appreciated.

The pseudo-code below illustrates what I am doing. Firstly a pointcloud is created and added, and then updated if it exists already.

```py
while True:
    if not 'pcd' in locals():
        pcd = o3d.geometry.PointCloud.create_from_rgbd_image(rgbd_image, camera_intrinsic, camera_extrinsic)
        # adding a new geometry
        vis.add_geometry(pcd)
    else:
        pcd_new = o3d.geometry.PointCloud.create_from_rgbd_image(rgbd_image, camera_intrinsic, camera_extrinsic)
        pcd.points = pcd_new.points
        pcd.colors = pcd_new.colors
        # updating an existing geometry
        vis.update_geometry(pcd)
    vis.update_renderer()
    vis.poll_events()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `vis.add_geometry(pcd, reset_bounding_box=False)`. This flag prevents recomputation of the view port bounding box.

The below code is an example where boxes are generated randomly and removed as well. Note that `remove_geometry` also has `reset_bounding_box` flag. Try changing `reset_bounding_box` to True to see the window flicker badly.

```
import random
import time

import open3d as o3d

def create_3dbbox_mesh(old_boxes):
    """
    Corner boxes are list of corner points in shape (3x8)
    """
    new_bboxes = []
    for bbox in old_boxes:
        if len(old_boxes) > 3 and random.random() < 0.1:
            # delete the bounding box
            continue
        new_bbox = bbox.translate([0.00001, 0, 0])
        new_bbox.color = [1, 0, 0]
        new_bboxes.append(new_bbox)

    if len(new_bboxes) < 8:
        bbox = o3d.geometry.AxisAlignedBoundingBox([0, 0, 0],
                                                   [1, 1, 1])
        new_bbox = bbox.translate([random.random(), random.random(), random.random()])
        new_bbox.color = [1, 0, 0]
        new_bboxes.append(new_bbox)

    return new_bboxes


# Create a visualization object and window
vis = o3d.visualization.Visualizer()
vis.create_window()
start_time = time.time()

curr_sec = int(time.time() - start_time)
prev_sec = curr_sec - 1

# create pcd object
point_cloud_o3d = o3d.geometry.PointCloud()

# Flag for first loop
create_o3d_obj = False
old_bboxes = create_3dbbox_mesh([])
prev_bboxes = create_3dbbox_mesh([])
for bbox_mesh in prev_bboxes:
    vis.add_geometry(bbox_mesh, reset_bounding_box=False)
while True:
    curr_sec = int(time.time() - start_time)
    if curr_sec - prev_sec >= 0.1:  # Increase time to slow down creation of new boxes or removal of old ones.
        prev_sec = curr_sec

        # 1: create bounding box meshes
        # function to create bounding box mesh using corner points
        bbox_meshes = create_3dbbox_mesh(prev_bboxes)

        # 2 Create a sample pointcloud
        dataset = o3d.data.PLYPointCloud()
        office = o3d.io.read_point_cloud(dataset.path)
        point_cloud_o3d.points = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(office.points)

        # 3: add or update geometry objects
        if not create_o3d_obj:
            vis.add_geometry(point_cloud_o3d)  # add point cloud
            create_o3d_obj = True  # change flag
        else:
            vis.update_geometry(point_cloud_o3d)  # update point cloud

        print(len(bbox_meshes))
        for bbox_mesh in bbox_meshes:  # add bbox_3d meshes
            vis.add_geometry(bbox_mesh, reset_bounding_box=False)

        for bbox_mesh in prev_bboxes:
            vis.remove_geometry(bbox_mesh, reset_bounding_box=False)

        prev_bboxes = bbox_meshes

    # 4 update o3d window
    if not vis.poll_events():
        break
    vis.update_renderer()

vis.close()
vis.destroy_window()
```

Comment: This indeed solves the issue. Thank you very much.